# When I switch this code to PDO it stops working with out emmiting any error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

> I'm trying to use PDO in my website in order to avoid SQL injections, well, as far as I'm concerned the following code is not safe, isn't it?
>   The problem is that when I switch my code to PDO no error is shown but
>   it doesn't work.

This is the code.

```
$q = ucwords($_GET['q']); 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT src FROM mydb WHERE $q LIKE 1");
$total = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$numRow = bcdiv(($total / 4), '1', 0);
if($numRow < 4){
    $numRow = 1;
    };
if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>              
    <h2>Resultados para la búsqueda <?php echo "$q"?></h2>
    <h3>Número de resultados total: <?php echo "$total"?></h3>
    <div class="gallery"> 
<?php       do{ ?>
                <style>
                .gallery{
                    grid-template-rows: repeat(<?php echo "$numRow" ?>, 10.375em);
                }
                </style>
                <div class="element" id="element"><img src="<?php echo $row['src']; ?>" alt=""></div>
<?php           }while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));{
                } ?>
<?php           }else{
                    echo "No hay resultados para la búsqueda";
                };
```

> This is the PDO prepared statement I tried

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT src FROM memes WHERE :q LIKE 1");
                    $stmt->bindParam(":q", $q, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()"); 
                    $result->execute();
                    $total = $result->fetchColumn();
                    $numRow = bcdiv(($total / 4), '1', 0);
                    if($numRow < 4){
                        $numRow = 1;
                    };
                    if($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        ?>              
                        <h2>Resultados para la búsqueda <?php echo "$q"?></h2>
                        <h3>Número de resultados total: <?php echo "$total"?></h3>
                            <div class="gallery">
        <?php           
                        do{ 
        ?>
                            <style>
                                .gallery{
                                    grid-template-rows: repeat(<?php echo "$numRow" ?>, 10.375em);
                                }
                            </style>
                            <div class="element" id="element">
                                <img src="<?php echo $row['src']; ?>" alt="">
                            </div>
        <?php
                        }while($row = $stmt->fetch());{
                        }
        ?>
        <?php
                    }else{
                        echo "No hay resultados para la búsqueda";
                    };
```

Comment: Show us PDO you created.

Comment: Plus _go research_ how to get error messages shown when using PDO, please. Make an actual effort to inform yourself _before_ asking here.

Comment: Just switching to PDO won't protect you against SQL injection. You need to use prepared statements, but tyou can also do that with mysqli.

Comment: a `SELECT src FROM mydb WHERE $q LIKE 1` query doesn't make too much sense. What you are trying to do here?

Comment: The $q is referred to a column. I'm sarching for all the values which have a 1 on that column